# Restricting direct access to ip address giving error

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to restrict direct access of my website through IP address. I want to only let people to see my website through domain.
When I made research I got one solution.

I added new VirtualHost in apache2 sites-available with my domain name and it worked with http://IP-ADDRESS but when someone try with https://IP-ADDRESS it can be accessible.
Again added another VirtualHost with port 433 to restrict https access too but it gives error.

My VirtualHost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 157.245.247.15
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site.com

    <Location />
                Order Allow,Deny
                Deny from All
        </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/157.245.247.15-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/157.245.247.15-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 157.245.247.15
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site.com

    <Location />
                Order Allow,Deny
                Deny from All
        </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/157.245.247.15-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/157.245.247.15-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Error :

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection157.245.247.15 sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Now i cannot access my website even IP or domain due to SSL Protocol Error. How it can be solved ?

My main goal is to block direct access to IP address in http or https.

My OS : Ubuntu

Web Server : Apache

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use an ip address as servername or serveralias. You should use an fqdn (resolved by a dns or by en entry in your hosts file)

Second: i can't see any configuration about the https. Where are key, certificate and chain configured?

Third: your configuration is denying access to everything

```
<Location />
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
    </Location>
```

and not giving access to anything else.